# Statsmodels: ARIMA giving less than specified number of predictions

Tags: python, statsmodels, arima

I'm using ARIMA on a time-series problem.  Specifically, I'm using Sklearn's `TimeSeriesSplit` to perform cross-validation.  Unfortunately, I'm getting 3 predictions when I've asked for 30.  Here's what I've done:

```
    Y_train = Y_train.astype(float)
    # build basic ARIMA model
    arima_model = ARIMA(Y_train, order=(2,0,1))
    # fit it
    arima_results = arima_model.fit()
    # predict next len(test) values
    preds = arima_results.forecast(steps=len(Y_test))
    print("len of y_train:", len(Y_train))
    print("len of y_test:", len(Y_test))
    print("len of preds:", len(preds))
```

And I get back:

```
len of y_train: 56
len of y_test: 30
len of preds: 3
```

This causes an error when I go to calculate `mean_squared_error` because predictions has a different length (3) than my test set (30).  Here's the error:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [3, 30]
```

Any idea what I'm bungling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.forecast), `fit` returns an instance of `ARIMAResults` which is what provides the `forecast` method.

The [return value is a `tuple`](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/tsa/arima_model.html#ARIMAResults.forecast), where each element is an array of suitable length with different types of result computations. So it appears you want to work with

```
preds[0]
```

instead of just looking directly at `preds`.